# How can I improve the reponsiveness of the virtual keyboard on my HTC Droid Eris?

Tags: touchscreen, keyboard, droid-eris

I've noticed that sometimes the virtual keyboard on my HTC Droid Eris can be very laggy.  While composing a text message, it will take a second or more to respond to some button presses.

Is there anything I can do to reduce the lag and make the virtual keyboard more responsive?

Comment: If someone with enough rep could create an htc-droid-eris tag and add it, I would appreciate it!

Comment: @Nick - done...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking out 3rd party keyboards. There are some free and paid alternatives that may show a nice improvement for you.

There are even stock keyboards for other phones that have been ripped out and placed online as APKs to download and install. Check out your favorite Eris/Android message board to get some suggestions, and also check the Market and try them there, too.